# Alert Popup Exception Handling Python Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, error-handling

I am trying to do Alert Exception Handling, I have tried a few options but I cant seem to get the script to try the exception, it just errors out.

```
#Add Alert Bypass
try:
    driver.switch_to.default_content()
except NoAlertPresentException:
    print('Alert Popup')
    alert = driver.switch_to.alert()
    alert.dismiss()
```

Error Message:

```
 Message: unexpected alert open: {Alert text : ...}
```

Comment: Can u show us the alert URL or code

Comment: You're trying to *handle alert* in case *there is no alert*! Maybe you should switch code in `try` and `except` blocks?

Comment: it is try and except...

Comment: Switching to default content shouldn't cause an alert to fire. Please post the relevant code that causes the alert to fire. That's where you need the `try-catch`.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your are using the wrong `selenium.common.exceptions` Based on the error message it looks like it is an unexpected alert. I would try using `UnexpectedAlertPresentException` rather than `NoAlertPresentException`